# gem to get coordinates with OpenStreetMap in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, openstreetmap

**TL;DR;**
Is there a gem to use in a form a openstreetmap?

**Problem:**
The idea is giving the user a way to pin a point of interest in a map inside a form in rails and get this coordinate and save it.

So, the use would be able to search the adddress and pin it on the map. I would then get the lat/lon from what the maps give and save in a entity called PointOfInterest. Is there a simple way to do this in ruby? I've been looking for it, but haven't found nothing.

I am using Rails 4.0.0 and ruby 2.0.0-p247

Comment: Are you able to embed html/javascript into your form? Then you could use  [LeafLet](http://leafletjs.com/) or [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org) for displaying a map and receiving events when the user clicks on a specific position.

Comment: @scai hey, can you post this as an answer? Ended using leaflet to do what I needed and it works like a charm :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to embed html/javascript into your form then you could use [LeafLet](http://leafletjs.com/) or [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) for displaying a map and receiving events when the user clicks on a specific position.

Answer (score 2):

[openstreetmap](http://rubydoc.info/gems/openstreetmap/0.2.1/frames) is a rubygem which can be an option to work with OSM and Ruby on Rails.